# Cheapest way from DTW Airport to Auburn Hills, MI?

Tags: usa, airports, michigan, dtw

I would like to know first if DTW is the most convenient International Airport nearby Auburn Hills, MI? 
And what is the cheapest way to get a ride from the Airport to Auburn Hills?

Comment: "Convenient" is a matter of personal opinion and depends on many variables. For example, some other airport might be closer to your destination but have flights from only a limited number of places: that airport would be more convenient if you can get flights to it and less convenient if it would require a 12-hour layover in New York. As for cheapest, we don't do price comparisons because the information quickly falls out of date, meaning the answer will likely only be useful to you and not any future visitors of the site.

Comment: note that these days on expedia, expedia **understands the concept of other airports near you**.  try it, look to the top left (or whatever it is) and you'll see suggestions of nearby airports.  Note that when you live in a rural area near a few major airports, you will surely choose which airport based on which airport offers a cheaper flight (and/or direct flight).  A 10 or 20 $ difference in ground travel costs won't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a map from gcmap.com showing all the airports near your target location that fly to London, UK. I chose that since almost anywhere will fly to London somehow. X marks your target location roughly. Which airport is best depends on where you are travelling from. There may be one or more stops from most of these airports, with DTW more likely to have a non-stop (or actually be on the route to/from the other airports).

[image]

I entered a random date searching for flights from FRA to DTW,XEC,YQG (YQG has complications since it's in Canada) and it does seem that DTW is the only reasonable option.

Looking on http://uberestimate.com, a typical UberX price from DTW to Auburn Hills is stated as $45-$58.

Google maps transport links to http://smartbus.org. However it's looking like a 3-3.5 hour journey to get to Auburn Hills rather than a 45 minute taxi ride. Are you interested in that?

Comment: As I understand DTW  will be the best choice, I am traveling from Frankfurt. Regarding the second question any thoughts  ?

Comment: I've updated my answer given your start point

Comment: That's what I was looking for !

Comment: Have a good trip!

Comment: For the record:  XEC is the Windsor, Ontario train station.  Probably no flights to Frankfurt from there.  YQG is Windsor International Airport, which is a tiny airport with a grand total of 5 gates and (currently) 11 flights per day;  so again, probably no flights to Frankfurt (or anywhere outside North America) from there.

Comment: Well XEC did show an itinerary on matrx, sometimes you do get rail-air links on one PNR. YQG was also on there too. I only gave airports that showed a "flight" on matrix to LON